# Entity Framework Convert DateTime to string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
leaves = leaves.Where(s => s.Employee.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.StartDate.ToString().Contains(searchString));
```

This will leads to an error..please help me,

Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat each case differently

```
DateTime dateValue;

if (DateTime.TryParse(searchString, out dateValue))
{
    leaves = leaves.Where(l => l.StartDate == dateValue);
}
else
{
    leaves = leaves.Where(s => s.Employee.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
}
```

Comment: it works fine just missing this,     leaves = leaves.Where(s => s.Employee.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));

Comment: @user1134291 Sorry about that missing part. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says exactly what is going on: Entity Framework cannot translate that part of the expression into a SQL statement, which means you cannot search this way.

Without more context, your best option is probably to search by real dates (i.e. search since or until a certain date).