# Convert Datetime to string entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datetime

I Have the following Method:

```
public List<REP_MEDIDORDISPLAY> GetAllMedidoresDisplay()
{          
    return ent.TB_MEDIDOR.Select(x => new REP_MEDIDORDISPLAY
    {
            Data_TOI = x.Data_TOI,
            Elemento = x.Elemento,
            Fase = x.Fase,
            KdKe = x.KD_KE,
            N_Equipamento = x.Numero,
            Tensao = x.Tensao,
            Status =  x.TB_REVISAO.Count > 0 ? "Revisão": 
                      x.TB_CHECAGEM_INTERNA.Count > 0 ? "Checagem interna":
                      x.TB_MESACALIBRACAO.Count > 0 ? "Mesa de calibração":
                      x.TB_HIPOT.Count > 0 ? "Hipot":
                      x.TB_INSPECAO.Count > 0? "Inspeção" :
                      x.TB_AGENDAMENTO.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID_Medidor == x.ID).Data_Agendamento.HasValue ?
                  --> Error here (x.TB_AGENDAMENTO.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID_Medidor == x.ID).Data_Agendamento.Value.ToString()) :String.Empty 
    }).ToList<REP_MEDIDORDISPLAY>();
}
```

But it's firing the following error when I try to convert a DateTime to String:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I hope you can help me guys, I need that value as string, I can't change that to datetime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Convert DateTime to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982910/entity-framework-convert-datetime-to-string)

Comment: I don't see how that would help me.

my convert is inside a subquery.

Comment: If you need this then Put another column to the table containing the date as string. Or write a stored procedure to get the same result.

Comment: There's no way to convert that to string? if I need to add a new column to the Class I'll have to change a lot of things =/

Comment: I am not on my computer to test this but why not use 

    `Data_Agendamento.Years + Data_Agendamento. Months + ....`

Comment: I think this could be a way out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework does not know how to execute `ToString()` method in SQL. So you should load the data by using `ToList()` and then translate into `SelectListItem` as:

```
return ent.TB_MEDIDOR.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
{ 
    Data_TOI = x.Data_TOI,
    ...
    // can convert DateTime to String here
})
// Then you can select this as a REP_MEDIDORDISPLAY if you want
.Select(y => new REP_MEDIDORDISPLAY
{
   Data_TOI = y.x.Data_TOI,
   ...
});
```

Comment: Calling `ToList` where you are will create the full entity. It's probably better to call `AsEnumerable` after selecting the `SelectListItem` items, then finishing with the final select.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that entity framework is converting your linq query to SQL. The error message is quite clear, it doesn't recognize the .ToString() method.

You will have to retrieve the results using entity framework and then perform the needed DateTime to String conversions.